# How to increment an index value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

The server returns JSON in the format

```
"games": [{
    "gameType": "RPG",
    "publishers": [{
        "publisher": "Square",
        "titles": [{
            "title": "Final Fantasy",
            "gameReleases": [ 2006, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2014 ]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

There is no numbered index which i need to populate a drop down later in the code, and i'm trying to add dynamically through Jquery.

So if RPG was selected this would be equivalent to 1, if the next item was Strategy this would be number 2 etc.  This would help me pass in items dynamically to a pluck command:

```
var i = $('gametypecombo').attr('value');
var getGameType = _.pluck(jsonData.gameType[i].publishers, 'publisher');
```

How would i add an index to item in order to achieve this.
My current code to populate the gameType drop down is:

```
var subGame = _.pluck(jsonData.games, 'gameType');
var gameType = _.map(subGame , function (val) {
return '<option value="' + index + '">' + val + '</option>';
}).join();
```

So it's the index in this code which i need to be an incrementing value.  Tried using a loop and _.each but no luck.

Thanks

EDIT:
Just to expand on the comment - when i'm outputting the index to the console it seems to work, each item in the drop down has an index value, then when i'm selecting an item from the drop down and outputting it to console the value is correct for that selection.
However as soon as i pass that as a variable to:

```
var getGameType = _.pluck(jsonData.gameType[i].publishers, 'publisher');
```

I get the error, any advice?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, when i've tried all of them i get the same error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'publishers' of undefined`

So this is a problem still with the 
`var getGameType = _.pluck(jsonData.gameType[i].publishers, 'publisher');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `data-*` attribute to store the index and the fetch it using `.data()`

```
var subGame = _.pluck(jsonData.games, 'gameType');
var gameType = _.map(subGame, function (val, i) {
    return '<option value="' + index + '" data-index="' + i + '">' + val + '</option>';
}).join();
```

then

```
var index = $('gametypecombo').find('option:selected').data('index')
var i = $('gametypecombo').val();
var subGame = _.pluck(jsonData.games, 'gameType');
var getGameType = _.pluck(subGame.publishers, 'publisher');
```

Comment: You don't really have to introduce a `data` attribute because the index will already be available in the `<option>` values. `$("#gametypecombo").val()` is enough.

Comment: Hi i've tried following your answer but i get the error above (updated my question) any advice?

Answer (score 1):

```
var index = 0; //global variable
var subGame = _.pluck(jsonData.games, 'gameType');
var gameType = _.map(subGame , function (val) {
return '<option value="' + index++ + '">' + val + '</option>';
}).join();
```

Comment: Hi, i've also attempted your answer which works the same way and i'm still getting an error.  I've provided more info on my question.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with increment operator?

Comment: I don't believe so, i tried the other answer listed without the increment and got the same answer.  If i replace my variable with a number data is returned, and if i create a fake variable set to a number and pass that in, it works.  However when i'm getting the number from the index i get an error.  I've tried parsing it, stringifying it.  Neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you're using jQuery, you can use `each` method with two parameters in the callback function - the first one will be index:

```
$.each(games, function(idx, obj) {
    //now idx is your index
    //and obj is the object corresponding to your index
});
```